# XML Parsing Error: Not defined entity .. When localizing Mozilla addon

Tags: xml, localization, xml-parsing, firefox-addon

I developing an addon based on English but with localisation support for German
 
It installs and works fine in English when when used in a German Firefox (locale changed etc)
Im getting an error
any ideas?

This is the error seen when clicking 'preferences' from the addon manager page ..

```
XML Parsing Error: Not defined entity
Address: chrome://addon/content/options.xul
Line No. 5, Column 1: <prefwindow
^
```

chrome.manifest ..

```
locale addon en-US chrome/locale/en-US/
locale addon de chrome/locale/de/
```

options.xul ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE addonDTD SYSTEM "chrome://addon/locale/options.dtd">  

<prefwindow
    id             = "addon-prefs"  
    title            = "&windowTitle.label;"
    xmlns            = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    onload         = "addon_Options.setButtons();">

<stringbundleset id = "stringbundleset">
    <stringbundle id =  "addon-options-string-bundle" src="chrome://addon/locale/options.properties"/>
</stringbundleset>
```

**EDIT**

contents of options.dtd

```
<!ENTITY    windowTitle.label       "App Einstellungen">
<!ENTITY    showPreferences.label       "Einstellungen öffnen, wenn Save Text to File gestarte wird?">
<!ENTITY    fileName.label          "Dateiname">
<!ENTITY    pathToFile.label        "Verzeichnis, um die Dateien zu speichern">
<!ENTITY    changeDirectory.label       "Verzeichnis wechseln">
<!ENTITY    datestamp.label         "Datum zum Dateinamen hinzufügen?">
<!ENTITY    timestamp.label         "Zeit zum Dateinamen hinzufügen?">
<!ENTITY    datestampInLine.label       "Datum vor dem gesicherten Text einfügen?">
<!ENTITY    timestampInLine.label       "Zeit vor dem gesicherten Text einfügen?">
<!ENTITY    lineSeparator.label     "Eine Leerzeile vor dem gesicherten Text einfügen?">
<!ENTITY    currentURL.label        "Den aktuellen URL mit dem Text sichern?">
<!ENTITY    saveMode.label          "Wie soll der Text gesichert werden?">
<!ENTITY    createFile.label        "Neue Datei erzeugen">
<!ENTITY    appendFile.label        "An die existierede Datei anfügen">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `<!DOCTYPE addonDTD` to `<!DOCTYPE prefwindow`

Comment: Have you checked options.dtd for typos?

Comment: cannot see any typos in options.dtd, i've included it in the question to be sure

Comment: Did you save it with a utf-8 text encoding?

Comment: No, they were saved as `Western (ISO-8859-15)`. Once saved to `UTF-8` they worked fine. thanks

Comment: Great. Just out of curiosity, does it work flawlessly with `addonDTD` as the root element of DTD declaration?